# How do I make a newly created list show up under "Lists" in SharePoint 2010? Sync names to outlook

Tags: 2010, outlook, quick-launch, menu-item

I am very new to SharePoint as you can probably tell by my question. I imported a list from an old TFS SharePoint site but I have to click on "Lists" to get to it. I would much rather appear as it's own link under "Links" the way "Calendar" and "Tasks" do. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Also, this list is a list of names, how do I sync the names to Outlook so that when you hover or click on their name it shows you their contact info? I assume this is possible because this is what happens on the old TFS Site where I got the list. When I imported the list I saw an option for a "Contacts" list but that only seemed to be available if you're creating the list from scratch. Do I have to create the list from scratch to get the desired results?

Answer (score 2):

1. You may need to enable the list to show up in the "Quick Launch". Go the your list, in the ribbon click on 'list' tab and click on list settings. Now click on 'Title, description and navigation' link. Ensure the option 'Display this list on quick launch' is set to 'yes'.

If you would like to reorder or change the name in quick launch, you can go to Site Settings (Site Actions Menu -> Site Settings), and click on 'Quick Launch'.

2. user information automatically shows up for columns if the type of column is 'People and Group'. You can go to list settings page (as above) and look at column type.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. The Quick Launch info was pretty spot on. Except, in site settings there wasn't a Quick Launch option, instead it was in Navigation. And for the user information, I clicked on the column and it has some radio buttons for options but "People and Group' isn't one of them. My options are: single lines of text, multiple lines of text, choice (menu to choose from), number, currency, or date & time. Also, how do you make a break in these comments sections without hitting enter and posting the comment?

Comment: So I tried to just create a new 'People and Group' column and add in the names then delete the old column. However, apparently in order to do anything easily in SharePoint, you need SharePoint Designer. And apparently where I work, you have to take some kind of class and get a certification in order to download the SharePoint Designer. So I tried to edit it by going into DataSheet view but the only options it would give me to add to the list appeared to be users or admins of the site... That list is currently very small because I haven't finished the site for users to be added. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, I had to grant all of these users permissions to the site but I've got the new column created with the contact info.